# join 3 tables to get values where there isn't a value in one of the values

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have three tables I'm looking to join. The thing is - I know there are values in 2 of the 3 values, but there could be something in the third table as well. I'm only looking to display values, that are not in the third table.

```
tbl1
ClientID    SvcGoalID        VendorID
17          7887             784

tbl2
ClientID    SvcGoalID        SvcAuthID
17          7887             634

tbl3
ClientID    SvcAuthID 
17          634
```

So basically this is a rough structure of my table, and here's what I'm looking for. I'm looking to join all three tables in a query - tbl1 & tbl2 using SvcGoalID and tb2 & tb3 using SvcAuthID - and only display data when there is NO value in tbl3 with the SvcAuthID. ANy help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `left join tbl3 on tbl2.SvcAuthID = tbl3.SvcAuthID where tbl3.SvcAuthID is null`

Comment: When you say no value in tbl3, do you mean no matching rows to JOIN with? (ie In your example if tbl3.SvcAuthID = 633, then you would now want to return data)

Comment: @scsimon - can't use ClientID - has to be SvcGoalID between tbl1 and tbl2 - those are the only unique values - i can have 20-30 records between tb1 and tbl2 for the same client, same goes for tbl3. I can only use svcGoalID and svcAuthID

Comment: Typo @yanman1234 but i fixed that... just a VERY strange data structure

Comment: @BobSki if that doesn't work we can use a sub-query in a similar fashion

Comment: @scsimon yeah it doesnt

Comment: @scsimon im getting no values whatsoever. I'm supposed to get over a 100, it's the join on tbl3 that gets me no values whatsoever, I thikn a subquery might be better

Comment: no, you shoudln't get any values based on that limited data set... i'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that you want to get the values from tbl1 and 2 where there is no value in tbl3. Here is the join structure as you have defined it...

```
declare @tbl1 table (ClientID int, SvcGoalID int, VendorID int)
insert into @tbl1
values
(17,7887,784)

declare @tbl2 table (ClientID int, SvcGoalID int, SvcAuthID int)
insert into @tbl2
values
(17,7887,634)

declare @tbl3 table (ClientID int, SvcAuthID int)
insert into @tbl3
values
(17,634)


select
    t1.*
    ,t2.*
    ,t3.*
from 
    @tbl1 t1
    inner join
    @tbl2 t2 on t2.SvcGoalID = t1.SvcGoalID
    left join
    @tbl3 t3 on t3.SvcAuthID = t2.SvcAuthID
--where
--  t3.SvcAuthID is null
```

If you run that query, you'll see it joins and returns as defined. If you uncomment out the where clause, that will return no rows because there is a join condition on tbl3. However. usually this is done when there are more rows to be had, and currently is pretty redundant.

Just a side note, your join structure basically makes these all an inner join. Adding a different value to @tbl3 changes this..

```
declare @tbl1 table (ClientID int, SvcGoalID int, VendorID int)
insert into @tbl1
values
(17,7887,784)

declare @tbl2 table (ClientID int, SvcGoalID int, SvcAuthID int)
insert into @tbl2
values
(17,7887,634)

declare @tbl3 table (ClientID int, SvcAuthID int)
insert into @tbl3
values
--(17,634),
(17,555)


select
    t1.*
    ,t2.*
    --,t3.*
from 
    @tbl1 t1
    inner join
    @tbl2 t2 on t2.SvcGoalID = t1.SvcGoalID
    left join
    @tbl3 t3 on t2.SvcAuthID = t3.SvcAuthID
where
    t3.SvcAuthID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first LEFT JOIN the secondary tables (in this case tbl1 and tbl2) then I would use a CASE statement.

For example:

```
SELECT
     3.ClientID
    ,CASE WHEN 3.SvcGoalID ISNULL THEN 2.SvcGoalID ELSE 1.SvcGoalID END
    -- Use above statement for all possible missing columns

FROM tbl1 as 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 as 3 ON 3.ClientID = 1.ClientID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 as 2 ON 2.ClientID = 1.ClientID
```